# DNG image resolution iOS?

Tags: ios, metadata, dng

I'm trying to figure out a way to read DNG image resolution without actually loading the image using CIFilter. So far I tried:

- CGImageSourceCopyMetadataAtIndex - doesn't have any resolution info at all in returned dictionary
- CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex - has only resolution of the embedded preview image

What do I miss? I'm sure there are apps that read that info somehow or do they use 3d party libs like libexif?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. CIFilter does not process the image unless it's rendered. But the image properties are available immediately through CIImage